# Defining isomorphism of rings of matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, ring-isomorphism

I'm having some difficulty with the following problem:

> Define an isomorphism of rings $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X]/(X^2) \cong A$
> where
> $A = \Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix}
>   a & a-b\\ 
>   a-b & a
> \end{pmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_5\Bigg\}$ is a commutative subring with unit of $\mathcal{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{Z}_5)$.

Knowing that a matrix of A is invertible iff $a+b \neq 0$ and that the set $N$ of non-invertible elements of A is a principal ideal and that $N$ is the only ideal of $A$ other than $(0)$ and A and which is prime.

Comment: What has the last paragraph to do with the question?

Comment: The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\ 2&1\end{bmatrix}$ with $a=1$ and $b=-1$ disproves the "invertible iff" claim in your post, since it has inverse $\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\ 4&3\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an error in the exercise. Suppose that there were a ring isomorphism $\varphi: \frac{(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[X]}{(X^2)} \overset{\sim}{\to} A$. Then
$$
\varphi(X) =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & a-b\\ a-b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Since $X^2 = 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} &=
\varphi(0) = \varphi(X^2) = \varphi(X)^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & a-b\\ a-b & a
\end{pmatrix}^2\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
2a^2 - 2ab + b^2 & 2a(a-b)\\ 2a(a-b) & 2a^2 - 2ab + b^2
\end{pmatrix} \, .
\end{align*}
This yields the system of equations
\begin{align}
0 &= 2a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = 2a(a-b) + b^2\\
0 &= 2a(a-b) \, .
\end{align}
Subtracting the second equation from the first, we have $b^2 = 0 \implies b = 0$, which then implies that $a = 0$, too. Thus
$$
\varphi(X) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
= \varphi(0) \, ,
$$
contradicting the hypothesis that $\varphi$ is injective.

Comment: +1 Nice proof, it looks well.

Comment: +1 If one wanted to adapt the exercise to work, then matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ 0&a\end{bmatrix}$ would have worked.  (just a thought for the OP)